# getting err- messages not defined in ejs file (when using flash in express)

Tags: node.js, express, ejs, express-session, passport-local

I am trying to print to print a flash message in ejs file. but it's throwing an error.

```
**ReferenceError: E:\nodeProject\views\login.ejs:10
    8| <body>
    9|     <h1>Login</h1>
 >> 10|     <% if(messages.error){%>
    11|         <%=messages.error%>
    12|         <%}%>
messages is not defined.**
```

**I have made server.js as my main js file. I have installed the required modules and the problem that is occuring is because it's not recognizing "messages.error" in my ejs file. Some statements in my main js (server.js)file are :**

```
const initializePassport=require('./passport-config');
const passport=require('passport');
const flash=require('express-flash');
const session=require('express-session');
const router=express.Router();

app.use(session({
    secret:process.env.SESSION_SECRET,
    resave :false,//if we want to resave the session variables if nothing has changed
    saveUninitialized:false//do u want to save an empty value if there is no value

}));
app.use(flash());
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session()); 

router.route('/login').post(passport.authenticate('local',{
    successRedirect:'/',
    failureRedirect:'/login',
    failureFlash:true, 
}));

initializePassport(passport,email=>{
    MongoClient.connect(url,(err,db)=>{
        if(err) throw err;
        const dBase=db.db();
        dBase.collection('Users').find({email:email},(err,res)=>{
            if(err) throw err;
            console.log(res);
        })
        return res;
        db.close();
    });    
});
```

**This is my passport-config.js file. Here i have declared the messages that passport should show as error if it occurs. My passport-config.js file is:**

```
const localStrategy=require('passport-local').Strategy
const bcrypt=require('bcrypt');

function initialize(passport,getUserByEmail){
    const authenticateUser= async(email,password,done)=>{
        const user=getUserByEmail(email);
        if(user==null)
        {
            return done(null,false,{message:"No user with this email found"});                                                                    
        }
        try {
            if(await bcrypt.compare(password,user.password)){
                return done(null,user);
            }
            else{
                return done(null,false,{message:"Password does not match "});
            }

        } catch (error) {
            return done(error);          
        }
    }
    passport.use(new localStrategy({userName:'email'},authenticateUser));  
}
module.exports= initialize;
```

** This is the ejs file where I am using the messages.error and getting the error that messages is not defined:**

```
<body>
    <h1>Login</h1>
    <% if(messages.error){%>
        <%=messages.error%>
        <%}%>



    <form action="/register" method="post">

    <div>
        <label for="name">Name</label>
        <input type="text" id="name" name="name" required>
    </div>
    <div>
        <label for="email">Email</label>
        <input type="email" id="email" name="email" required>
    </div>
    <div>
        <label for="password">Password</label>
        <input type="password" id="password" name="password" required>
    </div>
    <button type="submit">Login</button>
    </form>

    <a href="/register">Register</a>
</body>
```

Please have a look and tell me what's going wrong. I am a beginner, so please dont mind if my way of asking is inappropriate. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend setting up a middleware in your main server.js/app.js file like this:

```
app.use((req, res, next) => {
  res.locals.success = req.flash("success");
  res.locals.error = req.flash("error");
  next();
});
```

This is will ensure that the variable `success` and `error` are actually present.

And in your ejs file, do null check like this before using the variable: (Note here, use `error` instead of `messages.error`)

```
<% if(error != ''){ %>
```

A bit late but hope this helps!